# How do I break a loop inside the function and return a value for that function? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, loops

I would like to break the for loop here and return false so it doesn't keep testing the condition with the rest of the array elements and return the value I don't want it to return.
It's a code that's supposed to test the divisibility of the number by prime numbers that are smaller than 100.

```
var primenumbers = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97];
var primetest = function (a) {
for (i = 0; i < primenumbers.length; i += 1) {
    if ((a !== primenumbers[i]) && (a % primenumbers[i] === 0)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: the code you have written already does that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that both `return` statements are inside the loop so the loop will always only execute the first iteration and then return. It will never test for anything other than the first element in the array.

Solution: Move one of the statements out of the loop so that all array elements are checked and if none match, then the other return statement is executed:

```
var primenumbers = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97];

var primetest = function (a) {
    for (i = 0; i < primenumbers.length; i += 1) {
        if ((a !== primenumbers[i]) && (a % primenumbers[i] === 0)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is not that it won't exit when you want it to, it's that it exits even when you don't want it to.

Don't return anything in the `else` case, instead wait until the loop has finished to return the result that no match was found in the loop:

```
var primenumbers = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97];

function primetest(a) {
  for (i = 0; i < primenumbers.length; i += 1) {
    if ((a !== primenumbers[i]) && (a % primenumbers[i] === 0)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```